# Como fazer uma lista encadeada com Javascript que aponta para um elemento que eu queira?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lista-encadeada

Exemplo:
Eu tenho um array de blocos, cada bloco possui um objeto processo que tem um atributo estado, que pode ser livre ou ocupado. Como faço para que todo processo livre, aponte para o proximo processo livre mesmo tendo processos ocupados entre eles ?

Comment: Coloque este array como exemplo, e algum código que você tenha tentado, que facilita para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: se eu entendi sua pergunta, é simples manipulação de coleções usando puro javascript, ou com bibliotecas como d3.js e lodash.js. Lodash é bem mais amigável. https://jsfiddle.net/egidiocs/g8ovtadq/ [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WWadA.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WWadA.png)